# Trying to draw simple square using indices and vertices with PyOpengl

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I'm trying to create a 2D python game with Pygame.

But I realized that I could use PyOpengl, so I try to learn how use it. I'm able to create a triangle strip on my screen with the vertices. However, I would like to render these triangles using indices. In the code below,I tried to render a simple square with 2 triangles, 4 vertices in one list, and indices in another list.  Unfortunately I don't understand why the square doesn't appear. I probably misunderstood something about the handling of buffers, vaos, vbos or even pyopengl itself.
( I put comments to explain what I think the lines of code do )

```
import numpy as np
import pygame

from OpenGL.GL import *


vaos = []
vbos = []

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption("With OpenGl")
glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512)

# Creating vertices and indices
vertices = [-0.5, 0.5,
            -0.5, -0.5,
            0.5, -0.5,
            0.5, 0.5]

indices = [0, 1, 3,
           3, 1, 2]

# Creating VAO and binding it
vaoID = glGenVertexArrays(1)
vaos.append(vaoID)
glBindVertexArray(vaoID)

# Creating VBO for verticices and binding it
verticesID = glGenBuffers(1)
vbos.append(verticesID)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesID)

# Creating bufferData to store vertices position
verticesBuffer = np.array(vertices, dtype='f')
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

# Creating VBO for indices and binding it
indicesID = glGenBuffers(1)
vbos.append(indicesID)

# Creating bufferData to store indices
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesID)
indicesBuffer = np.array(indices, dtype='uint16')
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

# unbind VAO because I finished to use it
glBindVertexArray(0)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_o:
                run = False

    # Preparing screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)

    # Rendering
    # binding VAO
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID)

    # enabling VertexAttribArray to get vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

    # draw elements
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(vertices) * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)

    # disabling VertexAttribArray and unbind VAO because I finished to use them
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glBindVertexArray(0)

    pygame.display.flip()

# Cleanup
for vao in vaos:
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, vao)

for vbo in vbos:
    glDeleteBuffers(1, vbo)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a named buffer object is bound to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, the last parameter of [`glDrawElements`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDrawElements.html) is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. However, the type of the parameter has to be a pointer anyway (`ctypes.c_void_p`).

Hence, if the offset is 0, then the last argument can either be **`None`** or `ctypes.c_void_p(0)` otherwise the offset must be cast to `ctypes.c_void_p`.

In addition, the type argument must match the type of the indices in the buffer. Since the type of the indexes is `'uint16'`, the type argument must be `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.

The 3 possible combinations of index type and type argument are:

- 'uint8' - `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`
- 'uint16' - `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`
- 'uint32' - `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`

---

The correct code is either

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(vertices) * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)`</s>

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(vertices) * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
```

or

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(vertices) * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

Comment: I looked at my code and found that I put my indices type in `"uint16"` instead of `"uint32"`. I also modified the `glDrawElements` and it works with `None` and `ctypes.c_void_p(0)`.

Comment: @Thalrod_ `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`. I've extended the answer.